# Python | How to send a JSON response with name assign to it

Tags: python, json

How can I return an response (lets say an array) to the client with a name assign to it form a python script.

```
echo '{"jsonValidateReturn":'.json_encode($arrayToJs).'}';
```

in this scenario it returns an array with the name(jsonValidateReturn) assign to it also this can be accessed by jsonValidateReturn[1],so I want to do the same using a python script.

I tried it once but it didn't go well

```
array_to_js = [vld_id, vld_error, False]
array_to_js[2] = False
jsonValidateReturn = simplejson.dumps(array_to_js)
return HttpResponse(jsonValidateReturn, mimetype='application/json')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the last two lines:

```
jsonValidateReturn = simplejson.dumps({'jsonValidateReturn': array_to_js})
return HttpResponse(jsonValidateReturn, mimetype='application/json')
```